# import csv in mariadb

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.3, csv, mariadb

We import **csv** files in **mariadb**, 1 csv takes about 30 minutes. For **daily sync** of csv files thats about 3-4 hours and judge that as too much. 
Magento 2.3, Update on save is activated + Mysql tuner executed.
Both actions don't solve the issue.

We guess there is something to improve in the Magento tables. Does someone recognize the issue?

Comment: What you have using for import CSv to Marid db import

Comment: Also on which table those are import?

Comment: We use Firebear improved import v2.0.0 for importing csv and decided to upgrade first to the newest version

In csv we use columns with next headers: sku#weight#lengte#breedte#dikte#attribute_set_code#product_type#author#korting_leverancier#categories#product_websites#url_key#name#related_skus#uitgever#short_description#tax_class_name#description#price#levenscyclus#dienstverlening#orderafhandeling#allow_backorders#is_in_stock#visibility#product_online#base_image#levering24uur#levering48uur#qty

We dont know which tables are effected